# What are the things that I should mention and avoid in the introduction e-mail to my team in my new job?

Tags: new-job, team

I am joining my first job after my graduate studies. My manager asked me to send an e-mail to him with my short bio so that he will use it to introduce me to the entire team. I would like to mention my educational qualifications and interests outside work. I know the high-level idea of the product my team is working. Is it also fine to mention "how my skills will be helpful in improving the product"? I am a bit confused about this. I would like to know what are the things I should mention and as well as avoid in the introductory e-mail? Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A short bio is usually only a few sentences:

> I have just graduated from the University of Southern North Dakota with a masters degree in Musicology, with an emphasis on bassoon duets.  I also enjoy hiking and fishing.

So, give an emphasis on your studies and technical training, with (perhaps) a short sentence on your personal likes.  If your manager wants more details, he will ask for them.

You can mention your skills, but they are probably not looking for your opinion of how they can be helpful in improving the product.  You're just starting: listen and find out more before assuming you know what they need.

Answer (score 2):

1. Be modest. "I am new to the company and to the team, andf I thank you for the confidence you are extending to me by letting me join the [fill in the name] team and [fill in the name of the company or subdivision]
2. Say something nice about the team - "I've heard great things about the team and the company during the interview process and, needless to say, I accepted the offer and I am looking forward with working with you"
3. Express confidence - "I graduated with a major in [state the major] from [state the university] in [give the date]. I look forward to being a full fledged, fully participating, engaged member of the team".
4. Express positivity and good will. "I am looking forward to meeting and getting to know you all of you as a team and as individual members of the team over the next few days"
5. Try to get something from them - "Feel free to take me out to lunch any time :)"